# Prevent Visual studio to rebuild before publishing ClickOnce

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build, clickonce, publish

Im using Visual Studio Community 2017 (15.7.2) and used to be able to obfuscate my exe before publishing it using CodeFort. Since recently this is not possible anymore.

In the past, once I have built the release version of my application, I took the exe from the bin\Release folder, obfuscated it with CodeFort, copied the obfuscated file back and then publish to a UNC path. A quick check with IlSpy showed that the file was obfiscated & the result was indeed an obfuscated executable on each client using my ClickOnce application.

I suppose that Visual Studio now automatically rebuilds the project before publishing but I can't find a clear setting in Visual Studio. Does anyone has experience with this or knows if there is indeed a setting somewhere in Visual Studio allowing me to prevent this?

Thanks

Comment: Why cant you run the obfuscater in the build events?

Comment: Instead of preventing it, just have Visual Studio execute your obfuscator as a post build step.  In your projects properties, on the Build Events tab, set up your obfuscator to be run after a successful build.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your answers.. But in short, because it used to work like this and our obfuscation software if on another workstation.